# delay after setState is triggered

Tags: flutter, delay, sequential

in the code below that is for throwing dice, I want to wait 2 seconds after each dice throwing. I tested sleep(duration) and await Future.delayed(duration); the first one makes a delay before updating the screen which means when I tap the TextButton, it waits for 2 seconds and then changes the screen, but I want it to be changed and then waits for 2 seconds. The second one actually does nothing and there is no delays.
Here is the code:

```
Duration delay = const Duration(seconds: 2);
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can call delay inside `WidgetsBinding`, like this:

```
setState(() {
             ...
});
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 2));
  print("call"); // update the view then print call after 2 second
});
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. But my problem is that I want the players not to be able to change the dice numbers rapidly by tapping the button twice. I want the numbers to remain for 2 seconds before the users can tap again and change them. this code that you suggested works but does not prevent changing the numbers if the user taps the button rapidly. Do you know the solution to this problem?

Comment: you should set bool variable and before call the onpress function check for it. @محمدرضاحجتی

Answer (score 0):

try..

//Move your onPressCode to a function

```
Future<void> rollDice() async{
  
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 0), () {
     /// your onPressCode
  });
}
```

And on your onPress :

```
onPressed:() async {
  await rollDice();
  await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {});
  print('this print is show after 2 secs');
}
```

Edit ...

For prevent double tap, you can create a state called canPress with default value = false ...

```
onPressed:() async {
  if (canPress){
    setState(() => canPress = false);
    await rollDice();
    await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 2000), () {});
    print('this print is show after 2 secs');
    setState(() => canPress = true);  
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. But my problem is that I want the players not to be able to change the dice numbers rapidly by tapping the button twice. I want the numbers to remain for 2 seconds before the users can tap again and change them. this code that you suggested works but does not prevent changing the numbers if the user taps the button rapidly. Do you know the solution to this problem?

Comment: see the edit bro

Comment: Thank you very much. Now, it works perfectly. A small point is that the default value should be true. Thank you again